# How save all actions from users in MySQL Database - Java Application

Tags: java, mysql

I made a java application and to access it you must login.

There are 2 types of login: admin and normal user. I want to save information about all the movements of normal users. In other words I need to know which user added, changed or deleted anything from the database.

Is there any way to do this?

I know I'll have to create a new table in the database, but do not know anything else. Does anyone can help me clarify this doubt I have.

I honestly don't even know where to start.

I apologize if I did not make myself clear.

Thank all any help you can give me.

Greetings.

Any questions I will try to explain as best as possible.

Comment: Normally you log user movements to a log-file. System critical action like adding or deleting items would be stored in a db (audit). Main reason to do so it that you fill up your db on heavy client interaction. Another reason for using specific audit tables is that you want to add more info to the client action, like what was deleted. Accessing this data is easier if you have a column for that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a table like:

```
User   |  FormName  |  Action   |  ActionTime
```

And insert data into this table whenever an action is performed by the user.

For example:

When a product is added by the user. Insert that detail into this table.
Something like:

```
UserID   |  FormName  |  Action                |  ActionTime
1           Inventory    User added a product     2014-4-4 12:10:00
```

You will have to do whenever user add,edit,delete anything. So I would suggest a `static` function for that.

**EDIT:**

Now you can track a user by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserActionTable 
WHERE UserID=1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I realized what you meant to explain, but how do I save the data in that database new table? 
greetings

Comment: @user3320956: What you mean by `how`? The same way you store data to other tables.

Comment: Are you trying to say that when a user adds a product to the database, the same code that I use to store the product in the database, use the actions taken to save the newly created table?I'll accept your answer, but wanted to clarify my doubts.

Comment: @user3320956: You can use a stored procedure for storing the user actions to this table. Please let me know if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: Thank you. That was my question, how to populate the fields in the new table. 'll see how to make a stored procedure for storing the user actions to this table.

Comment: i will acepted your answer but if you could help me how to make the stored procedure really grateful :D

Comment: @user3320956: Edited my answer. BTW, you can find a bunch of result when googling it. Just start from [**here**](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Create trigger on database for insert,update and delete rows from database table. and when any operation perform on those table than trigger will be fire by database automatically at that time add row(data) in history table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

using above link you can perform this task easily.